# What's the best linux distro for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

What is the best linux distro for using QGIS? By best I mean:

1. Easy to install latest version with all plugins.
2. Includes QGIS map server and instructions for getting it running.
3. Is easily updated to the latest version of QGIS.

Currently, I have had unfortunate experiences on QGIS with Ubuntu and Fedora either using very old versions, breaking features during updates, missing core plugins, or lack of documentation. Which distro are QGIS developers running?

Comment: I know you said you didnt like Ubuntu but I consider it the best distro for QGIS imho.  And they have the Ubuntu GIS repository @ https://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/UbuntuGISRepository

Comment: This topic is primarily opinion-based but, I think that you can try out Debian testing. I also have had unfortunate experiences on QGIS, GDAL and PostGis with Ubuntu, however, I actually use Debian stable for my GIS purposes without problems.

Comment: Fedora ships 2.12...

Comment: If you don't like Ubuntu' s policy you can take Linux Mint. I had no problem installing the latest QGIS version on it.

Comment: @ed.hankins the ubuntugis ppa's don't contain the latest QGIS versions anymore. You have to add qgis.org as repository. See https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu for instructions.

Comment: I find it quite unfortunate that this question has been closed, because I find this question quite relevant. What is the Linux distro that has the best FOSS gis support? Where are the newest versions? Whats a good choice for stability of the GIS tools? Where will I have the least problems with dependencies? These are not necessarily opinion based questions.

Answer (score 2):

Debian and ubuntu are the most popular distribution and easiest to install qgis, in particurlaly if you want to access to the ltr version or the latest versions of qgis (2-12 and dev). All repositorys are given on the Qgis website : https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html

For the last question about developers, if you talk about Qgis Core dev team, I think they probably use the master one. If you talk about plugins developpers, it s not very important, because you have to test on different qgis version and all os to make sure not missing some bug.